# Paypal Webhook upon using Paypal Debit Card

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been looking everywhere for a solution. Hoping someone else has a solution.

Here is the scenario, I use [ClearCheckbook.com](https://www.clearcheckbook.com/) to keep track of the inflow/out flow of my accounts. I use their API to add transactions when I get a Paypal IPN I have a [script](https://github.com/bislewl/clearcheckbook_api) that creates the transaction in clearcheckbook.com. It works great from when I receive money. However if I pay with my paypal account or more commonly when I use my paypal debit card, it doesn't notify me. I would like to be able to do the same, where I have some sort of webhook/notification that. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, our Webhook and IPN systems do not support notifications for purchases (send money or debit card purchases). Both of these systems only support notifications for payments being received into your PayPal account. The only exception to that is the Payouts API, which is technically considered sending money to other accounts. The Payouts API is supported by our Webhooks system but no other purchase (send money) transactions are supported by our Webhook or IPN systems as of now.

An alternative option would be to use our Sync API to get your account reporting data. You could then implement a solution to parse that data and use the ClearCheckbook.com API to add the purchase transaction data into their system.

Here is a link to our Sync API for further information on how to use that API.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/sync/